# How to diagnose a failed capacitor on the mainboard?

Tags: repair, maintenance, 80286

My Fox II 286 mainboard just blew a capacitor. I haven't yet powered it on, so maybe the cap was bad. How can I diagnose this problem, and eliminate other bad caps?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The wear of solid electrolyte tantal caps as these are is neglectable. They are however extremely sensitive to overvoltage. As this is a cap right near the power connector, I suspect the power supply is broken.

This seems to be the +12V or -12V line. Check these on the power supply before reconnecting. Maybe you are lucky and nothing else got fried.

(Chances you accidentally mixed up the two halves of the power connector? What you have there at the back of the photo also doesn't seem to belong to an AT power supply.)

Comment: I am using an ATX2AT connector with a brand new modular ATX power supply. I put the black grounds in the middle. The supply works with another vintage mainboard.

Comment: I don't see any reason not to power up this old board. That cap isn't strictly required for function.

Comment: I measured the other tantalum caps now and i see a bunch of them seemingly shorted out

Comment: @Arne that can be caused just by IC protection (some ICs short circuit pins while powered down to protect from static voltage)

Comment: @Spektre but then the cap won't be shorted, or?

Comment: @Arne it would ... the only not shorted pins (in such case) would be the main power of ICs on which the Caps are usually used for ...  but those are usually Electrolyte with high capacity...

Comment: @Spektre well the shorted ones are at the ISA slots. The board is ancient and does not have any electrolytics.

Comment: "neglectable" - do you mean *negligible*?

Comment: Ah, yes, negligible.

Comment: Solid tantalums that old ARE known to wear and sometimes catastrophically fail spotaneously exactly the way shown, when connected to a power source capable of substantial current.

Comment: This isn't related to wear as far as I know.

Comment: If they are used in circuits that abuses them with higher-than-spec inrush currents, probably also installed using out of spec soldering methods... then yes, they can wear... best replace them all with low esr aluminiums :)